# persistant non-utf-8 characters in scraped file

Tags: html, python-3.x, web-scraping

i am currently learning web-scraping, and i am trying to save the html version of the page:
"https://www.wuxiaworld.co/Master-Hunter-K/1061716.html" by using Beautiful soup and requests modules.

And every time i get these ï»¿ characters at the  stat of the html file and â€¦â€ instead of "

this is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
link = "https://www.wuxiaworld.co/Master-Hunter-K/1061716.html"
html = requests.get(link,timeout = 2)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text,'html.parser')
with open("test.html","a",encoding ="utf-8-sig") as file:
    file.write(str(soup))
```

any help would be appreciated. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, That's called `HTML` `BOM` stands for `Byte Order Mark` [BOM Meaning](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-byte-order-mark.en)

Let's see what happened exactly here is the following:

```
import requests

r = requests.get(
    'https://www.wuxiaworld.co/Master-Hunter-K/1061716.html')
```

```py
print(r.headers['Content-Type'])
```

> text/html

So let's check for encoding !

```py
print(r.encoding)
```

> ISO-8859-1

That's is the default for `HTML4` but for `HTML5` will be `UTF-8`

So now we need to make it `apparent` using requests.

So we will use

```py
r.encoding = r.apparent_encoding
print(r.encoding)
```

> UTF-8-SIG

Final Code is below:

```
import requests


r = requests.get(
    'https://www.wuxiaworld.co/Master-Hunter-K/1061716.html')
r.encoding = r.apparent_encoding
with open('page.html', 'w', encoding='UTF-8-SIG') as pop:
    pop.write(r.text)
```

Comment: Please add explanation as well along with the code, to make it understandable how it will solve the problem.

Comment: @ArunVinoth you have it now, so you can understood

Comment: thanks Mr.Ahmed i was searching for the solution for a the past 2 nights and you helped to get it right.